# ProgressBar usando Threads e SceneBiulder

Tags: thread, javafx

Estou fazendo um trabalho, e eu queria saber de uma maneira simples como eu resolvo isso, eu estou fazendo um programa simples em que é quase que um jogo, basicamente, você aperta um botão, a barra de progresso começa a crescer, e adiciona 1 ponto em uma Label. só que quando eu coloco pra funcionar, ele realiza os dois ao mesmo tempo e o ponto vai antes da barra de progresso se concluir, alguém poderia me ajudar?

#### Método no *Controller*:

```
@FXML Label lb$;  
int dinheiro = 0;  

@FXML  
    public void botão() {  
        BarraDeProgresso b = new BarraDeProgresso(100, 90, barra);  
        new Thread(b).start();  
        dinheiro++;  
        lb$.setText(String.valueOf(dinheiro));  

    }
```

#### Classe *BarraDeProgresso*:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;  
import javafx.concurrent.Task;  
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;  

public class BarraDeProgresso extends Task<Void>{

private int qt;
private int tempo;
private ProgressBar barra;


public BarraDeProgresso(int qt, int tempo, ProgressBar barra) {
    this.qt = qt;
    this.tempo = tempo;
    this.barra = barra;
    barra.setProgress(0);
}

public void inicia() {
    double incremento = 1.0/qt;
    for(int i=0; i<qt; i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(tempo);
            barra.setProgress(barra.getProgress()+incremento);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

//gets e sets implementados
```

Comment: Boa tarde otavio, sugiro que poste o que você já conseguiu fazer, dê uma olhada nesse link sobre [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Atente-se para certos padrões sobre perguntas, pois é difícil saber como ajudar se você não nos der um rumo, e bem vindo à comunidade

Comment: Coloquei os códigos, melhorou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma correta de marcar o progresso em JavaFX é utilizando um bind em conjunto com os métodos [updateProgress](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress(double,double))/[updateMessage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage(java.lang.String)). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
Task<Void> tarefa = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            updateMessage("Pontos: " + i);
            updateProgress(i, 9); // (trabalho atual, total)
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return null;
    }       
};

Label label = new Label("0");
label.textProperty().bind(tarefa.messageProperty());

ProgressBar pg = new ProgressBar();
pg.progressProperty().bind(tarefa.progressProperty());
```

O método [setProgress](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#setProgress(double)) do ProgressBar apenas coloca o muda o valor da propriedade mas não serve para incrementar.